# Error while converting RDD to Dataframe [PySpark]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to convert an RDD back to a Spark DataFrame using the code below

```
schema = StructType(
        [StructField("msn", StringType(), True),
         StructField("Input_Tensor", ArrayType(DoubleType()), True)]
         )
DF = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema)
```

The dataset has only two columns:

- `msn` that contains only a string of character.
- `Input_Tensor` a 2D array of float.

But I keep having this error and I'm not sure where it's coming from :

```
File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/myproject/datasets/train.py", line 51, in EMA_detector
    DF = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema)
  File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 790, in createDataFrame
    jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
  File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2364, in _to_java_object_rdd
    return self.ctx._jvm.SerDeUtil.pythonToJava(rdd._jrdd, True)
  File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2599, in _jrdd
    self._jrdd_deserializer, profiler)
  File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2500, in _wrap_function
    pickled_command, broadcast_vars, env, includes = _prepare_for_python_RDD(sc, command)
  File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2486, in _prepare_for_python_RDD
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/tmp/conda-d3f87356-6008-4349-9075-f488e0870d02/real/envs/conda-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/serializers.py", line 694, in dumps
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)

_pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

**EDIT:**

My RDD comes from this :

```
rdd = test_data.mapPartitions(lambda part: vectorizer.transform(part))
```

The dataset `test_data` is itself an RDD but somehow after the `mapPartitions` it's a `pipelinedRDD` and that seems to be why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `rdd` is defined by the following data:

```
data = [("row1", [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]]), ("row2", [[7.7, 8.8, 9.9], [10.10, 11.11, 12.12]])]
```

Then you can use `toDF()` method which will infer the data types for you. In this case `string` and `array<array<double>>`

```
>>> sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["msn", "Input_Tensor"])
DataFrame[msn: string, Input_Tensor: array<array<double>>]
```

The end result:

```
>>> sc.parallelize(data).toDF(["msn", "Input_Tensor"]).show(truncate=False)
+----+---------------------------------------+
|msn |Input_Tensor                           |
+----+---------------------------------------+
|row1|[[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]]     |
|row2|[[7.7, 8.8, 9.9], [10.1, 11.11, 12.12]]|
+----+---------------------------------------+
```

However, you can still use `createDataFrame` method if the tensor is defined as a double array in the schema.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, ArrayType, DoubleType, StringType
data = [("row1", [[1.1, 2.2, 3.3], [4.4, 5.5, 6.6]]), ("row2", [[7.7, 8.8, 9.9], [10.10, 11.11, 12.12]])]
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
schema = StructType([
             StructField("msn", StringType(), True),
             StructField("Input_Tensor", ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType())), True)])
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=schema).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was using  `toDF() ` but I was getting the same error, I though it was coming from schema inference. But it might be coming from me not defined my 2D array as a `ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType()))`. Code's running I'll let you know if that works

Comment: I've updated my post, I think it's coming from the step just above where my RDD is the result of a `mapPartitions`